# How do I get my notification to drop down when I notify in Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, notifications

When I show a notification in Android, the notification gets placed in the notification area in Android. I can see it when I pull down, but it does not auto-drop down like I have seen many apps do. How do I force the notification to drop down? Is this possible while my app is open? Does it only drop down if my app is closed or not full screen?

I'm using Xamarin and here is my code (which was basically copied from Google's own example):

*UPDATE* Code snippet now works and shows a "heads up" notification.

```
string title = activity.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Label_VideoSaved);
string text = string.Format(activity.Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Text_FileLocation), OutputFile);
Notification.Builder b = new Notification.Builder(activity);
b.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
b.SetContentTitle(title);
b.SetContentText(text);
b.Extras.PutString("video", OutputFile);

// create a "heads up" notification with the following 2 lines:
b.SetPriority((int)Android.App.NotificationPriority.High);
b.SetVibrate(new long[0]);

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(activity, typeof(ViewVideoActivity));
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(activity);
stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ViewVideoActivity)));
stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
b.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
notificationManager.Notify(0, b.Build());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is a "heads-up" notification:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Heads-up

> Examples of conditions that may trigger heads-up notifications include:
>
> The user's activity is in fullscreen mode (the app uses fullScreenIntent),
>
> The notification has high priority and uses ringtones or vibrations

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize the priority and vibrate had to be set specifically. I added this code and it works:             b.SetPriority((int)Android.App.NotificationPriority.High);
            b.SetVibrate(new long[0]);